# Prevent to click "Add to Cart" button if specific product not selected - Shopify

Tags: shopify

Hi experts have a nice day,
I have a project on Shopify where I'm getting struggled on how to prevent and make alert when a specific product selected for some conditions.

I made a product template where I populate list of products from collection A as a first set of selection and collection B as a second set of selection.

This is a product page where I can select 1 product from collection A and also 1 product from collection B  (Each product has Add to Cart button)

The condition is collection A is required to have a least 1 product added from collection B while collection B does not required to have product from collection A.

Here is I wan't to achieve:
when either products from collection A button clicked it will alert like
"Need to select at least 1 product from collection B"

I'm using cart.js for the multiple products in a product template.
Is this possible? or is there's a simplest way to implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the inner workings of `cart.js`, but what you're asking for should be reasonably straightforward with regular Javascript.

What it sounds like you want to do is:

- On submit of Form A;
- Select Form B;
- Check if Form B has a variant selected;
- Prevent the add-to-cart action if no variant in Form B

If `cart.js` has an easy way to insert a validation function, that's where I would insert the code. Otherwise, I would add the validation function to the form submit or click of the submit button, whichever is more convenient with `cart.js` being in play.

A sample validation function would look something like:

```
function validateFormA(evt){
  var formB = document.forms('product-form-b'); // document.forms can access any form on the page using the appropriate ID attribute

  if(!form){
    // Couldn't find form, should this pass or fail?
    return;
  }

  var variantIdField = form.id;  // To access the form control with the name 'id'
  var value = variantIdField.value;
  if(!value){
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```